# how to add new items in jquery to do list when enter is pressed

Tags: jquery

im new to jquery and need some help making the to do list add new items when enter is pressed. its working when you click on the button but nothing is happening when enter is pressed. any help is very much appreciated thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>


  </head>
<body>

<form name="toDoList">
  <input type="text" id="listItem" name="ListItem" />
</form>
<ol>
</ol>
<button id="btn2">Add something</button>
<p>something</p>
<p>ldldl</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    var toAdd = $("#listItem").val();
    $("ol").append("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>");
  });
  $("#listItem")keydown(function(e) {

  if (e.which === 13) {

      var toAdd = $("#listItem").val();
      $("ol").append("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>");
    }
  });
});

$(document).on('dblclick', 'li', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('strike').fadeOut('slow');
});



</script> 


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$("#listItem").keydown()`, you got syntax error

Comment: methods (like `.keydown()`) should be preceded by a dot.

Answer (score 0):

- You're missing a dot in nesting your method `.keydown`
- You're missing an `event.preventDefault` that should prevent the form to be submitted:

```js
$(function() {

  $("#btn2").click(function() {
    var toAdd = $("#listItem").val();
    $("ol").append("<li>" + toAdd + "</li>");
  });

  $("#listItem").keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();   // Don't submit the form
      $("ol").append("<li>" + this.value + "</li>"); // append this.value
      this.value = "";  // reset the value field
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="toDoList">
  <input type="text" id="listItem" name="ListItem" />
</form>
<ol>
</ol>
<button id="btn2">Add something</button>
```

But hey...

```js
$(function() {
  
  var $input = $("#listItem"),
      $list = $("ol");
  
  // Don't repeat yourself. Use functions!
  
  function addListItem(e) {
    if(e.type==="keydown" && e.which !== 13) return;
    e.preventDefault(); // Don't submit form
    $list.append("<li>" + $input.val() + "</li>");
    $input.val(""); // Reset input field
  }
  
  $("#btn2").click(addListItem);
  $("#listItem").keydown(addListItem);

  // See the beauty? now you know they both perform the same
  // addListItem() task and you only have to change the code in one place
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="toDoList">
  <input type="text" id="listItem" name="ListItem" />
</form>
<ol></ol>
<button id="btn2">Add something</button>
```